# Ruby on rails - How to associate with generated folders that are nested/sub folders of other folders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested, associations, scaffolding

I have a folder named admin that has a generated scaffolding in it named products that also has the primary_key, id, changed to ect. I then created a model called cart_products that has a `belongs_to :product`. When I try to use it like:
 `@cart.cart_products.create(product: @product, quantity:)`, it throws a name error, saying

> Rails couldn't find a valid model for Product association. Please provide the :class_name option on the association declaration. If :class_name is already provided, make sure it's an ActiveRecord::Base subclass.

So I then changed the belongs_to to `belongs_to :product, :class_name => "Admin::Product"` which is the name of the product model. Now I am getting an

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid - SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: main.products

Where did `main.products` come from when in my database it is saved as `create_table "admin_products", primary_key: "ect", force: :cascade do |t|`?

This is what My code looks like:

```rb
# controllers/home/cart_controller.rb
class Home::CartController < HomeController
  def add
    @product = Admin::Product.find_by(ect: params[:ect])
    # Code breaks on next line
    @cart.cart_products.create(product: @product, quantity:)
  end
end

# models/cart_product.rb
class CartProduct < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product, class_name: "Admin::Product"
  belongs_to :cart
end

# models/admin/product.rb
class Admin::Product < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :cart_products
    has_many :carts, through: :cart_products
  end
end

# models/admin.rb
module Admin
  def self.table_name_prefix
    "admin_"
  end
end
```

The Database that I am trying to access is:

```rb
# associated with models/admin/product.rb
create_table "admin_products", primary_key: "ect", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.decimal "price"
    t.text "description"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

```rb
# associated with models/cart_product.rb
class CreateCartProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :cart_products do |t|
      t.belongs_to :product, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.belongs_to :cart, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.integer :quantity

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: When you generated scaffold, make sure you run `rails db:migrate `

Comment: I have already done that and the schema has been created for it

Comment: So, Change `belongs_to :product, :class_name => "Admin::Product"` to `belongs_to :product, :class_name => "AdminProduct"`

Comment: When I do that is says **Rails couldn't find a valid model for AdminProduct association. Please provide the :class_name option on the association declaration. If :class_name is already provided, make sure it's an ActiveRecord::Base subclass.**

Comment: When you generate `admin_products` table. Make sure have `AdminProduct model`

Comment: I do have a model for it, but since it is a sub-folder of the admin folder it is named as `Admin::Product`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to tell *rails* the table name:

```rb
# app/models/admin/product.rb
module Admin
  class Product < ApplicationRecord
    self.table_name = "admin_products"
  end
end
```

Or add prefix to every table for models in *Admin* module.

```rb
# app/models/admin.rb
module Admin
  def self.table_name_prefix
    "admin_"
  end 
end
```

**Update**

Rollback your `CreateCartProducts` migrations and update it to fix foreign key constraint:

```rb
# NOTE: by default when foreign key constraint is created
#       the name of the foreign table is inferred from
#       the argument `:product`. There is no `products` table,
#       which is why SQLite complains about it in the error;
#       custom primary key has to be also specified.
# t.belongs_to :product, null: false, foreign_key: true
t.belongs_to :product, null: false,
  foreign_key: { to_table: :admin_products, primary_key: "ect" }
```

Run migrations again. This should fix it.

Also, it's probably best to set up *PostgreSQL* for development. It would have raised an error when trying to run that migration, but *SQLite* seems to be ok with migration but complains later.

---

*https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-table_name*

*https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference*

Comment: I don't know why but the module admin is not being called

Comment: rails version is 7.0.3

Comment: I have updated it

Comment: @Ese10 models look fine. why do you say *Admin* module is not being called. `Admin::Product.find_by` line is working, right? What's in `CartProduct` migration? is it `t.references :product`?

Comment: Yes, that is how it is referenced

Comment: @Ese10 see the update. it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Always run after scaffolding with any model

> rails db:migrate

Answer (score 0):

Is your model file **admin/product.rb**

```
class Admin::Product < ApplicationRecord
```

If yes, then you need to have class_name with associations as below

```
belongs_to :product, class_name: "Admin::Product"
```

Comment: Yes that is how my model file is but when I use that `belongs_to :product, class_name: "Admin::Product"`, it says **SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: main.products** but the model table that I have is `admin_products`